# vue class binding on variable of object

Tags: css, vue.js, binding

I have a project where I need to do form validation. If the fields are not correctly entered the formErrors object will get a string variable with the correct error text. So in the case of email the error String will be put in `formErrors.email`. This String can be printed out in the p element that shows the error even the visibility of this p element can be shown or hidden depending on the state of `formErrors.email` like `v-if="formErrors.email"`.

But when I try to give the input element a red border color using `:class="{formErrors.email : text-red-primary}"` the linter throws an error `Parsing error: Unexpected token .`. But how do i enable this class binding with a variable inside the formErrors object.

```html
<input
          type="text"
          name="email"
          id="email"
          v-model="email"
          placeholder="Email address"
          class="w-full px-4 py-3 border rounded-lg text-black-primary focus:outline-none text-sm"
          :class="{formErrors.email : text-red-primary}"
        />
        <p v-if="formErrors.email" class="text-red-primary text-xs mt-1 ml-1">{{formErrors.email}}</p>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class binding is currently backwards: the key should be the class name, and the value should be truthy/falsy (e.g., a non-empty string would be truthy). Also, the key (`text-red-primary`) needs to be quoted because it contains non-alphanumeric characters (`-`):

```html
<!-- ❌ -->
<input :class="{ formErrors.email : text-red-primary }">

<!-- ✅ -->
<input :class="{ 'text-red-primary' : formErrors.email }">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create computed property say `isEmailInValid` which return true/false

and use it in template like this

```
:class="{'text-red-primary': isEmailInValid}"
```

dynamic class gets applied when condition is true only.

You can checkout vue docs for more info https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html